# Listen to the/a class

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idiomatic-language, collocations

Can we say, “listen to the/a class,” to mean “listen to what the teacher teaches or says in class”? For example, can we say something like,

> “All good students listen to the class properly”?

Or can a teacher say to his students,

> “Listen to the class”?

I know on the university level we could say, “Listen to the/a lecture” but it may not be appropriate for lower levels than the university level. I also think that “listen to/a the class” could mean “listen to the members of the class”. So I wonder if we can use the same phrase to mean listening to what is going on in class. Do you think it is appropriate usage?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that one of the meanings of "class" is "all the students," and I think this is the first meaning that would be thought of. A teacher might address the students by saying "Now **class**, listen..." So "listen to the class" might sound like the opposite of what was meant.

"Listen to the lecture" could be appropriate even below university level, if the teacher is really talking for so long that it could be called a "lecture." But maybe the simplest is "Listen to the teacher"?

Comment: What do you think about “listen to the lesson”?